# Magento 2.1.0 How to edit admin template of subitem grid of bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, bundled-product, bundle

I am trying to make changes in sub item grid details of bundle product.

[image]

In magento 1 it was set form __construct method of **app\code\core\Mage\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option.php**  as `$this->setTemplate('bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml');`

and when i make any change in `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\bundle\product\edit\bundle\option.phtml` it is reflecting properly.

**Please note i am not making changes directly in core files this is just for confirmation i am using it.**

But when i look into the _construct method of **\vendor\magento\module-bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option.php** setting of template is not their.

and when i tried to make changes in `\vendor\magento\module-bundle\view\adminhtml\templates\product\edit\bundle\option.phtml` no changes being reflected.

If I enable a path hint for admin it shows me that it appears from `\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\ui_component\templates\form\collapsible.xhtml`

but their is no as such code which shows for this grid.

Can any one please tell me from where this details comes in magento2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel::getBundleSelections()`. This is the class where the various columns are created ('Is Default', 'Name', 'SKU', etc.).

If you want to add an extra column (which is my guess, it's not very clear from your question what you're trying to achieve), you should hook into this method. However, this method is protected, so if you want to do it the 'Magento 2 Way', you should create a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) that executes after `Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel::modifyMeta`, and alters the array.

Beware that this is a very deep nested array, so you should do some digging to find the proper node, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: From where position of element is decided? Suppose if i want to change position of Add products to option button then? and what is the role of option.phtml in magento2 then